# How to remove back button and others from layout editor

Tags: android-studio, graphical-layout-editor, layout-editor

In **Android Studio layout editor**, how can I remove the bar at bottom of screen which contains back button and task switcher ( check attached image), so I can preview whole page?

**I need this just for preview while I am designing app, not in run time.**

[image]

Comment: You should try with navigation bar color transparent in `Style.xml` .

Comment: @jaydroider I need this just for preview while I am designing app, not in run time.